# remap specific key combination in one application only (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping, greasemonkey

I have a Mac (specifically Snow Leopard), so I'm used to Cmd+* to do things. My mail, for bold, underline, and italics, uses Ctrl+b/u/i instead of Cmd+b/u/i. How can I remap these three key combinations for one application only, or do something similar?

Comment: I think it might help if we new what Mail application you are using -- maybe there is a way to tweak that instead?

Comment: It's Prism, which is based on Firefox, and my webmail (Project Phoenix from AOL). I hadn't thought of this, but could GreaseMonkey or something similar help me out here?

Comment: Could something like this serve as the basis for a solution: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/9539? Added greasemonkey tag.

Comment: *bump*!  I need this too for Remote Desktop for Mac!  I've swapped CTRL and COMMAND system-wide in the Keyboard Preferences (under Modifiers) so the keyboard more closely matches Windows, but then RDP re-reverses them making my Windows now act like the Mac keyboard! Ugh!

Comment: @MarqueIV Comments don't bump topics on this site. Also, your problem is rather unrelated to this topic, as it is very specific to every program whether it's possible or how to do it. Consider posting a new question. I might have an idea how to solve it, so feel to ping me by @-replying to any of my comments.

Comment: @Dan, how is my question any different?  I would like to remap key combinations for a specific application.  Isn't that *exactly* what this post is?  Granted, I explained my use-case, but the issue is I would like certain key combinations to work differently in one app vs. the others, and this is at the system, not the app level (i.e. these are not related to menu commands or such.  These are related to the keyboard itself.)

Comment: @MarqueIV In that case, don't. I believe I'd have had an answer for your question though, if you'd  be willing to use a different RDP client. The answers to this question show you that it's not really possible to do in general.

Comment: @Dan, I don't mind which client I use.  (Actually, I'm pretty peeved at MS for their lack of multi mon in their Mac client since the wondows one does just fine.)  Feel free to write me at Mark[aht]MarkDonohoe[dotkom] and let me know.  I'm all ears!

Comment: Bump, I have the same question.  Different problem space, I want to remap CMD+V but only with some applications.  In certain applications, I almost never want to paste with the original style (for example mail).  In these apps, I want to switch the paste and match style keystroke with the paste keystroke.

Comment: @Frobbit, as Daniel Beck mentions above, comments do not bump topics here. Additionally, the answer I would recommend for you would be user495470's. If this does not work, that's the start of a new question you can ask, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Prism or web applications, but for normal OS X applications there's the Keyboard Shortcuts preferences:

[image]

You can also modify the property list that stores the shortcuts directly with something like:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "New Message" "@Y"
```

Comment: The problem is, there's no menu entry, so I can't bind a custom keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: Lri, could you explain the link you posted? It looks really cool but ... I don't quite understand what it does

Comment: @kalaracey The whole script is a bit off-topic so you could've posted the comment for the Gist instead. But I edited it to contain a sample  text file.

Comment: Hey @Lri, your link seems to be down.  Can you re-upload your file?

Comment: @MarquelV Sorry, I removed the Gist after posting the script on my website at http://lri.me/appshortcuts.